# Swift have an observer on any change to node (value) but also retrieve the previous value prior to change

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am adding an observer as such:

```
handle = pools.child(pID).child("Scores").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    etc...
```

which observes whenever there is a change to the `Scores` node.

What I am looking for clarity in is if it's possible to get the `original` value before the score changed using Swift; as it is possible when utilizing Firebase functions where you can get the previous value!?

Comment: have you tried (by any chance) the `object.observe(\.value, options: [.old, .new]) { _, value in /* value.oldValue OR value.newValue */ }` for getting info about the _before_ and _after_ values?

Comment: @holex I have not tried that, can you explain further, I have not seen any documentation in regards to this for iOS/Swift!? Can you provide full sample code?

Comment: that is in the latest Swift 4 documentation and comes from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID12) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID205) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID57)